# dplyr self-join with filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to subtract values from a row with label "baseline" from all the otherwise marked items in a long format data frame. It is easy to do this in two steps using a left_join with the "baseline" subset. However, I could not figure out how to combine `vas_1` and `vas_diff` into one chain.

```
library(dplyr)
# Create test data
n_users = 5
vas = data_frame(
  user = rep(letters[1:n_users], each = 3),
  group = rep(c("baseline", "early", "late" ),n_users),
  vas = round(rgamma(n_users*3, 10,1.4 ))
)
# The above data are given


# Assume some other operations are required
vas_1 = vas %>%
  mutate(
    vas = vas * 2
  )
# I want to put the following into one
# chain with the above
# Use self-join to subtract baseline
vas_diff = vas_1 %>%
  filter(group != "baseline") %>%
  # Problem is vas_1 here. Using . gives error here
  # Adding copy = TRUE does not help
#  left_join(. %>% filter(group == "baseline") , by = c("user")) %>%
  left_join(vas_1 %>% filter(group == "baseline") , by = c("user")) %>%
  mutate(vas = vas.x - vas.y) %>% # compute offset
  select(user, group.x, vas) # remove temporary variables

vas_diff
```

Comment: So what is the desired result? Your code works. Are you just trying to simplify it or you want a different result?

Comment: No, results are fine. I am interested in the inner workings of dplyr, especially the magic of dot. And trying to understand the error message requesting a copy, failure even with "copy"

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question but the problem seems to be that you filter out all observations where `group == "baseline"` and then, later in the pipe, you want to access those rows again but they are not in the data any more. Perhaps you want something like `vas_1 %>% left_join(filter(., group != "baseline"), filter(., group == "baseline"), by = c("user")) `?

Comment: @docendo discimus: This does not work for me because `left_join` joins on the `%>%`, and has only one parameter when used in the chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use anonymous function when `.` should be used multiple times:

```
... %>% (function(df) { ... }) %>% ...
```

Hence, in your case:

```
vas_diff = vas_1 %>%
  filter(group != "baseline") %>%
  (function(df) left_join(df, df %>% filter(group == "baseline") , by = c("user"))) %>%
  mutate(vas = vas.x - vas.y) %>% # compute offset
  select(user, group.x, vas)
```

(which is not going produce desirable result as describe in comments above, but you it shows how to use anonymous function)

but probably you want this:

```
vas_diff = vas_1 %>%
  left_join(
    x = filter(., group != "baseline")
    , y = filter(., group == "baseline")
    , by = c("user")
  ) %>%
  mutate(vas = vas.x - vas.y) %>% # compute offset
  select(user, group.x, vas) # remove temporary variables
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar option, and a demonstration that you can pass whole pipe chains as arguments to the join. Instead of moving the `.` inside `filter`, you can pass `.` as an argument to `eval`, then remove unwanted columns in the right-hand side. This is largely just to document this approach for my own purposes.

```
vas_diff = vas_1 %>%
  left_join(x = eval(.) %>% 
                  filter(group != "baseline"),
            y = eval(.) %>% 
                  filter(group == "baseline") %>%
                  select(-group),
            by = c("user")) %>%
  mutate(vas = vas.x - vas.y) %>% # compute offset
  select(user, group, vas)
```

Does anybody know why you can't simply pass the `.`, like `x = . %>% filter .....`. Why do we need to `eval(.)`.

Comment: When I was very young and beautiful, my mother told me that `eval` is evil.